# Animation is not supported Exception

Tags: animation, bada

When I try to run FormTransition in UiControlAnimator (SDK example) I get an exception saying

"0086.598,EXCEPTION,P32,T00,A124,Osp::Ui::Animations::FrameAnimator::GetStatus (126) > [] Animation is not supported."

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because my pc does not have graphics card that supports OpenGL® 2.1.

Reference: http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppappprogramming.help/html/dev_guide/ui/animation_handling.htm